# Rails 3: getting undefined method when trying to use a variable in a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I'm getting `undefined method 'social_system' for #User:0x000001052e2ad8`. I thought i'd be using the value in the block, can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
# User model:
facebook_url    string
google_plus_url string

# Constants defined in User model:
SOCIAL_SYSTEMS      = [ 'facebook_url', 'google_plus_url' ]
SOCIAL_SYSTEM_NAMES = { 'facebook_url'    => 'Facebook',
                        'google_plus_url' => 'Google +' }

# View (going to be a helper eventually)
<%  User::SOCIAL_SYSTEMS.each do |social_system| 
      url = @user.send(social_system)
      if url %>
        <p><a href="<%= url %>">
          <%= User::SOCIAL_SYSTEM_NAMES[social_system] -%>
        </a></p>
<%    end
    end
%>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this should work. I assume the error is froming from the `@user.send(social_system)` line. What version of Ruby are you using? You can *try* `@user.send(social_system.to_sym)`, but that is just a guess, because the `send` method should be able to take strings just fine, unless there is a difference in Ruby 1.9.2 that I don't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, since the error msg is

`undefined method 'social_system' for #User:0x000001052e2ad8.`

that implies that "social_system" is being treated as a string const, not as a variable.

Try echoing it to see what is being sent. The *variable* `social_system` should only have values of 'facebook_url', 'google_plus_url'

Echo test:

```
# View (going to be a helper eventually)
<%  User::SOCIAL_SYSTEMS.each do |social_system| 
%>
<p>social_system = <%= social_system %> 
<% #      url = @user.send(social_system)
   #   if url %>
   #     <p><a href="<%= url %>">
          <%= User::SOCIAL_SYSTEM_NAMES[social_system] -%>
        </a></p>
<% #   end
    end
%>
```

Comment: I had to delete out the commented lines but then i was getting "social_system = facebook_url Facebook

social_system = google_plus_url Google + " which is what we want correct?

Comment: Hey Larry I figured it out because of your message on another thread "Model attributes are implemented as methods. Carefully check the spelling and capitalization of the attribute name against the name in the constant array." if you want to add that to your answer above I'll give you the check mark for this one. Thanks again.